# Jquery Issue when displaying dialog dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function in my js file.

```
var updateUploadImgBtn = function () {
    var $levels = $('.personalization-level').last();
    var levelID = $.trim($levels.find('.PersonalizationLevel-level-id').val());
    alert(levelID);
    $(".uploadImg").click(function () {
        if (levelID != 0) {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        } else {
            alert("Please save the personalization level before adding new images.")
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        }
        return false;
    });
    $levels.find('.uploadImg').attr("onClick", "setPersonalizationID('" + levelID + "');");
    $levels.find('.viewButton').attr("onClick", "loadImagesPersonalization('" + levelID + "');");
};
```

I am also adding and removing rows dynamically and then this function updates my buttons for correct functioning. One of them opens a dialog depending on the levelID (when its saved I get the levelID and I can add Images.) But when removing the newly added row. I am getting BOTH of the if courses?

The alert is printing the correct levelID.

Any help guys?

Comment: Put an alert just above your `if (levelID != 0)` call.  My guess is that you have something simulating a click once the row is added

Comment: saw the problem, i need to have the levels variable declared inside my jquery click handler